# Implementing wave system

Tags: c#, xna

this is my code for loading the enemies I was trying to implement a wave system that go's to next wave after killing all enemies or time limit I'm was looking for a way to implement it thanks :)

```
public void LoadEnemies()
    {

        if (spawn >= 1)
        {
            spawn = 0;
            if (enemies.Count() < 5)
            {
                SpawnEnemy(new Vector2(1500, 100));
                SpawnEnemy(new Vector2(1600, 200));
                SpawnEnemy(new Vector2(1700, 300));
                SpawnEnemy(new Vector2(1800, 400));
                SpawnEnemy(new Vector2(1900, 500));
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
            if (!enemies[i].isVisible)
            {
                enemies.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You must ask a *question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if the enemy count equals 0 in your update, or better yet, make an `OnDie` event and have it check to see if the enemy was the last.

```
if (enemies.Count == 0)
    //Move on
```